# How to manually destroy wxMenu

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxAuiToolBar button which when clicked shows a menu. The menu also has a sub-menu which carries information on recently opened files.

The following code is called when the user clicks on a button on `wxAuiToolBar`:

```
m_MainMenu = new wxMenu();
m_RecentFilesMenu = new wxMenu();
wxMenuItem* Item = nullptr;


Item = m_MainMenu->Append(ID_OPEN_FILE, "Open...");
Item->SetBitmap(wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_FILE_OPEN));

for (const auto& path : m_RecentFiles->GetList())
{
    if (!std::filesystem::exists(path))
        continue;

    int ID = wxNewId();

    wxString p = path.wstring();
    m_RecentFilesMenu->Append(ID, p);

    wxObject* obj = (wxObject*)(new wxString(p));
    m_RecentFilesMenu->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &pnlScriptEditor::OnRecentFiles, this, ID, wxID_ANY, obj);
}

m_MainMenu->AppendSubMenu(m_RecentFilesMenu, "Recent Files");

    
m_MainMenu->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &pnlScriptEditor::OnOpen, this, ID_OPEN_FILE);

PopupMenu(m_MainMenu);
```

Things work as expected; however, I think `m_MainMenu` is leaking the memory since wxWidgets does not take ownership for PopupMenu. If I call `delete m_MainMenu` the program crashes due to access violation. Note that in this case it is not possible to allocate `m_MainMenu` on stack.

How to manually destroy `m_MainMenu` or should I destroy it?

---

**EDIT #1:**

1. If `m_MainMenu` is declared on the stack then as soon as the popup
   menu closes the following error is issued in debug mode: "Exception
   thrown at 0x000001ED1D2852A0 in sciencesuit.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
   violation executing location "
2. Commenting out `m_RecentFilesMenu->Bind` part in the for loop then there is no crash.
3. Removing `obj` which has been created using `wxObject* obj = (wxObject*)(new wxString(p));` from `m_RecentFilesMenu->Bind` prevents the crash.

I assume since wxString is not inherited from wxObject, during cleanup unexpected access violation happens. For example, instead of casting wxString to wxObject, if the following is done, then there is no crash.

```
class RecentFileData :public wxObject
{
public:
    RecentFileData(const std::filesystem::path& path)
    {
        m_Data = path;
    }

    auto GetPath() const
    {
        return m_Data;
    }

private:
    std::filesystem::path m_Data;
};
```

then,

```
auto Data = new RecentFileData(path);
m_RecentFilesMenu->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &pnlScriptEditor::OnRecentFiles, this, ID, wxID_ANY, Data);
```

Since `RecentFileData` inherits from `wxObject`, wxWidgets can nicely do its internal cleaning up.

---

**EDIT #2**

Based on suggestion from VZ, the following way of handling greatly simplifies the code:

```
if (m_RecentFilesMenu)
    m_MainMenu->Destroy(ID_RECENTFILES);

m_RecentFilesMenu = new wxMenu();

for (const auto& path : m_RecentFiles->GetList())
{
    if (!std::filesystem::exists(path))
        continue;

    int ID = wxNewId();

    m_RecentFilesMenu->Append(ID, path.wstring());
    m_RecentFilesMenu->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, [this, path](wxCommandEvent& CmdEvt)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenScriptFile(path);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            wxMessageBox(e.what());
        }
    }, ID);
}

m_MainMenu->Append(ID_RECENTFILES,"Recent Files", m_RecentFilesMenu);
```

Note:

1. `m_MainMenu` is allocated on the heap therefore some menu items of
   the `m_MainMenu` are re-used and only the submenu is destroyed and
   re-created.
2. Since `Bind` uses lambda expression there is no need for `RecentFileData` class.
3. If the capture is done using reference `[&]` the program crashes. Therefore, a copy of the `path` variable must be allowed to be created by the lambda expression thus `[this, path]` capture.

Comment: Seems like having `m_MainMenu` in the constructor of the wxPanel and using `Append(ID_RECENTFILES,"Recent Files", m_RecentFilesMenu);` instead of `AppendSubMenu` and then using `Delete(int ID)` solves the problem. Therefore `m_MainMenu` is only created once. However, I am still curious to learn what would be the best way of destroying a `wxMenu`.

Comment: You don't have to destroy the menu. Did you get a repot of a leak from the MSVC or valgrind?

Comment: @Igor: Frankly I haven't checked with either. However, continuously allocating the memory and not deleting it (wxWidgets tells us it does not take ownership) gave me the feeling of a memory leak. I know sub-menu is handled but not the owner menu.

Comment: 1) Your post does not show how/where/when you are deleting `m_MainMenu`. Since that is a local variable, why are you using `m_` which typically means a class member? 2) Yes, you need to `delete` `m_MainMenu` after the call to PopupMenu(). 3) You should also add the location when calling. `PopupMenu(menu, event.GetPoint()`. 4) I would not do this `wxObject* obj = (wxObject*)(new wxString(p));`. Create a class with a wxString member and allocate an instance of that class for the object. 5) This appears wrong `&pnlScriptEditor::OnOpen`.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Your point on #4 is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code indeed leaks a `wxMenu` pointer and you need to add `delete m_MainMenu;` after the call to `PopupMenu()` to fix it (or use `std::unique_ptr<>` instead of manually allocating and freeing memory, of course). The crash in the original version is indeed due to deleting a `wxString` via a pointer to `wxObject` which is invalid ("undefined behaviour") and can't be done. Your solution with a wrapper class deriving from `wxObject` is fine, even if there are fancier and arguably nicer ways to avoid using client data pointer completely (define a lambda and capture the data in it instead).

But if this is really how your code looks like, I see no reason not to allocate `m_MainMenu` on the stack, and it's not clear why do you think it's impossible.

However creating popup menus on the heap is supported and actually pretty useful if creating it takes some time, as you can create it only once and then show it multiple times later.

Comment: I added more info, hopefully it will make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, it's clear now, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of lambda expression, indeed a much better way. Updated the question accordingly.